# Inject hash into sam file. Is possible?

Tags: passwords, windows

I have a very uncommon scenario. I have a Windows 10 laptop with a specific configuration. On that configuration, there is a user (local user, not domain user) which I don't know its password. I want to migrate that user to another Windows 10 computer trying to keep its password.

Of course I already tried to decrypt the password. I already extracted the hash from the SAM file and tried some unsuccessful rainbow tables attacks using *ophcrack*, but the goal is not to hack the account, but to create the user in the same state on a new laptop.

I already have administrator rights on both laptops. I also tried *metasploit*+*mimikatz* unsuccessfully but the user never logged on the computer so I guess *mimikatz* can't work on this.

Does anybody know a way to achieve something like this?

Comment: I think chntpw can do this. You'll need to boot second computer off live CD/USB

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this tool. I'll try it. Maybe you can put the same as an answer and if it works I'll mark it as resolved. Thanks.

Comment: It seems with that application you can reset the password... but can't inject the hash I already have. :/ Any alternative or idea? There are a lot of methods to reset the password but it seems there is no option for what I want to do.

Comment: Oh well. A simple source code change could probably add that feature, but looks like you got a better answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely possible after a recent updates to both Mimikatz and Meterpreter. Please refer to the following links:

- https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/8549
- https://twitter.com/gentilkiwi/status/872588656967548928

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Windows 10. I was upgrading my desktop to a 1050 ti and forgot the admin password to download new drivers. What I did:

- Take out the SSD or the drive that stores Windows
- Use an adapter and plug it into another computer where you have admin rights
- Open the SAM file through regedit and hive edit the hash for a blank password (look it up on Google the hash should be somthing like x0) and hive save.
- Plug the SSD or drive back in and you will be able to get in without a password.

Then you can migrate.

Comment: Unless you used Bitlocker...

Comment: ...And a Bitlocker bypass method like the one in the news recently